# How to know if something is wrong with my SSD

Tags: ssd

I build a PC some time ago, and from the get go I have been having problems with is. I brought it to the store where I ordered the parts, and they said my graphics card was damaged, and they replaced it.

As a note they said my SSD could be a little unstable also. So after raplcing of the graphics card the system runs a little better, but I get crashes again. It always crashes when I do stuff with graphics. Either do 3D benchmarks, or video rendering on highest quality.

Also when I install the newest drivers from NVIDEA, the system crashes on boot.

I removed my ssd, and placed in a normal HDD, and formatted the system. Now everything seem to run fine.

I have no clue what to do. Is it even possible my SSD is the cause of instable graphics. Is there a way for me to test if my SSD is any good.

It's a OCZ Vertex 4 - 128GB

--

Edit..

Well, i'm trying to format my SSD now, from within windows which is installed on the HDD now and my machine crashes also. But before I head to the store again I want to know for sure if it is the SSD.

Comment: If your system becomes unstable or crashes while the SSD is connected, it's safe to assume there is something wrong with it. You seem to have already diagnosed the problem. Contact the manufacturer for support. I looked at the OCZ site and did not find any utilities to run on the drive.

Comment: I've the same problems with graphics. But my pc has normal HDD.
Thank you for your question! Maybe my graphic crashes in the same way.

Comment: Yeah this is the second GTX660 I got from the store that is giving me somewhat the same problems. Not exactly the same they, the system is just very unstable.

Comment: You may need to update firm where for the drive. Curent version v1.5.2 that addresses "stability issues with some legacy chips" as per the release notes.http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_Vertex_4_and_Agility_4/

Comment: This would be an interesting question if you phrased it a little differently and actually asked a question.

Comment: @Saif Bechan  How to see if anything is wrong with XXX? ->  Test **only** that part in a known good computer. If it works fine there then move to the next doubtful component. This includes SSDs, cables PSU's and other components.

Comment: @KronoS Ok, next time when I have a problem I will not try and describe my problem, but I will try and create a question that is interesting for you to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic steps include:

1. Can you read/write to the drive? Usually, the writing is the impaired part
2. Does the manufacturer have a test program? I know that Intel has the SSD Toolkit for download
3. Does your OS support TRIM? It's possible it's reached its EOL if TRIM wasn't turned on. [This page](http://forums.legitreviews.com/about23670.html) has instructions for Windows 7:

   1. Open the Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
   2. Type `fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify`, and press Enter
   3. Look at the output:

      **DisableDeleteNotify** = 1 (Windows TRIM commands are disabled)
      **DisableDeleteNotify** = 0 (Windows TRIM commands are enabled)

Comment: How do I know if my OS supports trim, I am running windows 7 pro.

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 supports TRIM. [This page](http://forums.legitreviews.com/about23670.html) describes how (will edit answer)

Comment: Ok, I will try that next. I can't say if my previous installs had TRIM enabled tho. But can this just crash your PC. My PC just freezes, no blue screen or that kind of stuff, just freeze or instant reboot. ANd only when I do heavy graphics.

Comment: If it only does it when doing heavy graphics, I'd be looking at the Graphics card and Power Supply unit too